# UPDATE SQLite table, JS, PhoneGap, passing variable

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am finding that in order to pass a variable to my database table I am having to create the variable as a global, which I would prefer not to do. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the variable passed without using an anonymous function instead of "updateSelectedBird."

```
updateBirds(3); //this is normally called from within another function

function updateBirds(_birdIndex) {
    var db = window.openDatabase("birdingDB", "1.0", "Birding DB", 200000);
    birdIndex = _birdIndex;
    db.transaction(updateSelectedBird, errorSelBirds);
}

function updateSelectedBird(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('UPDATE Birds SET sighted = "1" WHERE id = ' + birdIndex);
}

function errorSelBirds(err) { /*error function*/ }
```

Any help would  be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I was having the same issue, but I found a work-around you have to use annoynmous self-calling functions. Annoying =/

```
db_callback = function(tx) {
   for(var x in data) {
     (function()
        var _tmpX = x;
        tx.executeSql("select from bla bla bla", [], function(tx2, result) {
           console.log(_tmpX); //atleast this time it increments and isn't the last key of the data collection.   
         });
      })();
   }
}
```

I had this issue, because I wanted to check if data existed in the table already, while peforming a sync from the server. (I needed to check if rowID was in there already or not, since you can create things from the phone to!) - it became a tricky situation. And now I'm worried about memory consumption =/

Hope this helps you out however